# Is there any way to track who has disabled/enabled the SQL Agents Jobs in MS SQL SERVER 2016

Tags: sql-server

What are the different ways one can track (DBA) who has disabled/enabled the SQL Agents Jobs in MS SQL SERVER 2016?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow :) please share more info about your problem. like sharing codes, images and everything that could lead us to a better answer for your question. Also be noted to ask questions related to problem, not open discussion and stuff that are general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL server doesn't capture job modification.
Alternatively, you can create a trigger in system table dbo.sysjobs to record this.

Comment: No - you should never attempt to manually alter system tables.